# How do I select last element in table before table id with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to select an li element inside of a giant table.

Breakdown:

- Some TR's have a "sectionheader" class as seen in the attached photo where it says "used"
- I need to click the last highlighted li of the TR *before* the one with sectionheader containing text "Used" (As pictured)

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2jdW.png)

Comment: //tr[@class='sectionheader']/td/b[contains(,,'Used')]/preceding-sibling::tr[1] Should give you the trs before the ones containing that text in the b tag you could swap the /td/b for an and if it just needs to contain used anywhere in the tr tag.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan can you explain ::tr[1] ? If i want to click the li with the href and the edit id as pictured would I just add .click() after tr[1]?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.